# Javascript on hover for > 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write vanilla javascript which will listen for if a img is hovered over, and if the image is hovered over for 3 seconds it opens a new tab. Currently I am doing something like this

```
 img.addEventListener('mouseover', changeDefOver);
img.setAttribute( 'class', 'myCssClass' );
```

```
function changeDefOver(e) {
  window.open("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org", "_blank");
}
```

but this will do it instantly and does not check for the 3 seconds. I also cannot use jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: try storing the time + 3 seconds in a variable, then when the time reaches the time in the variable, then you know that 3 seconds of mousedown have passed.

Comment: popup blocker will probably block it

Comment: So is is possible to do?

Comment: ^^ That won't work because it needs to know if your mouse is hovering over the image for 3 seconds

Comment: the new tab should not open if you hover the image for < 3 seconds

Answer (score 3):

So use timeout and remove the timeout if the user leaves the element.

```
function over() {
  this.timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('here')
  }, 3000)
}

function left() {
  if (this.timeout) window.clearTimeout(this.timeout)
}

img.addEventListener('mouseenter', over);
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', left);
```

Comment: this is good. Only problem is that it seems to open a bunch of tabs instead of just one

Comment: well _blank opens a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Popup blocker would probably block this, but you could use `setTimeout.`

```
let hoverTimeout;

function changeDefOver(e) {
  hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
     window.open("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org", "_blank");
  }, 3000);
}

function clearHoverTimeout() {
   clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
}
```

But you'll also need to clean up the timeout:

```
img.addEventListener('mouseout', clearHoverTimeout);
```

Comment: is it possible to replace any occurences of the `img` with something else in the case that the `img` is an AD? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Not particularly. Ads are usually served from within iframes. But you could make your selector more specific to only have this code trigger on your own images. Add a class to the ones you want to target and only bind the event to those

Comment: also, the link I want to open, instead of geeksforgeeks is a link that requires their longitude and latitude. I have been trying `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` but it seems to be giving issues. Any ideas?

Comment: A user needs to give permission for that I believe. Like when you see a popup that asks if the site can use your location

Comment: It seems the idea @epascarello had is good, but sometimes opens a bunch of tabs. is there a way to only open one?